# node.js non-blocking POST request to wait for another POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, post, asynchronous

So I'm working on a text based game where users send post requests to the server written in node.js. However, I need to match 2 players together by letting the first player to wait for the 2nd player before submitting a response. The problem right now is that after I call the post request once, I cannot send another post request for any response. It seems like the first thread is blocking any more future requests. What should in terms of using callbacks and async. I do not want to use sockets if possible as that will limit the languages that players can code in.

```
var newGame=0;
//joins new game (username,password)
app.post('/game/join', function(req, res) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    if(newGame==1){
        res.send('Game Started');
        newGame=0;
    }
    else{
        newGame=1;
        wait(username, function(){
            res.send('Game Started'+username);
        });
    }
});

function wait(username){
    while(newGame==1){
        console.log(username + newGame);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js is single threaded so your code is preventing your server from processing additional requests. Blocking the event loop is def something you don't want to be doing.

I was going to request using something like Socket.IO or WebRTC but I saw your constraint. I'm not really sure what you meant by "limit the language players can code in"

Comment: Thanks! Since node.js is single threaded, I think its better for me to write the server in python. My complaint for the languages was to allow players to play by just sending POST and GET requests which I think is no longer feasible. If that is not the case, I think python better suits my needs for the project.

Comment: @user5590696 you can still use Node.js for what your doing, BTW you just need to make sure your code is asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

So you may have found that once your wait functions starts, nothing else happens.  This is because an infinite while loop with a blocking call (console.log) prevents the event loop from doing anything else until it is 'done'.  You can include waiting with setTimeout, setInterval, and clearInterval to run a function at some point in the future, run a function on an interval, and stop running a function on an interval, respectively.

```
var newGame = 0;

app.post('/game/join', function(req, res) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;

    if (newGame === 1) {
        res.send('Game started' + username);
    } else {
        var wait = setInterval(function() {
            if (newGame === 1){
                clearInterval(wait);
                res.send('Game Started');
                newGame = 0;
            }
        }, 5000); // retry every 5 seconds
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

For me, its not clear that how you pick 2 users to start a match. If it is like, one player is connected and another one is joining and then the match is started between them, I would do something like this.

```
var waitingResponses = [];
//joins new game (username,password)
app.post('/game/join', function(req, res) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    if(pendingJoinRequests.length) {
      var waitingPlayerResponse = waitingResponses.shift();
      waitingPlayerResponse.send('Game Started'+username);
      res.send('Game Started');
    }
    else {
      waitingResponses.push(res);
    }

});
```